# How do you check what modules come with standard python?

Tags: module

How do you check what modules come with standard python? is there any sort of code to run to retrieve the modules i have access to?

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6463918/how-can-i-get-a-list-of-all-the-python-standard-library-modules