# How to determine if a module name is part of python standard library

Tags: python, python-2.7

I have a module name **as a string** (e.g. 'logging') that was given by querying the **module** attribute of an object.

How can I differentiate between modules that are part of my project and modules that are part of python standard library?

I know that I can check if this module was installed by pip using pip.get_installed_distributions(), but these are not related to the standard library

Note: I'm working on python 2.7 so solutions that are valid only in python 3.x are less relevant.

Unlike the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6463918/how-can-i-get-a-list-of-all-the-python-standard-library-modules), I was looking for a solution that can be run in O(1) and will not require holding an array of results nor having to scan the directory for every query.

Thanks.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I get a list of all the Python standard library modules](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6463918/how-can-i-get-a-list-of-all-the-python-standard-library-modules)

Comment: I'm curious to know why you want to do this in case there's some other way to solve what you're trying to do.

Comment: As a rule, you don't want to do that. E.g. when the codebase will be run by a different Python version, some modules may move between being stock and 3rd-party/backports. If your problem is that your import syntax is ambiguous, then make it unambiguous instead e.g. by fully qualifying the modules or with relative imports.

Comment: Also looking at the duplicate, this answer with isort might be better, at least for me I already had it installed instead of stdlib_list. https://stackoverflow.com/a/21659703/3387223

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Quick 'n dirty solution, using the standard module [imp](https://docs.python.org/2.7/library/imp.html):

```
import imp
import os.path
import sys

python_path = os.path.dirname(sys.executable)

my_mod_name = 'logging'

module_path = imp.find_module(my_mod_name)[1]
if 'site-packages' in module_path or python_path in module_path or not imp.is_builtin(my_mod_name):
    print('module', my_mod_name, 'is not included in standard python library')
```

Comment: As an example of ways in which this fails, it won't detect modules imported from the script's directory. "Quick and dirty" is an apt description.

Comment: I know. "Quick 'n dirty" is there for a reason ;) I added a refinement to include modules imported outside python install folder.

Comment: @user2357112, do you have other examples of how this may fail? Guillaume's update seems to fix this issue.

Comment: @YohaiDe: The update fixes that problem, but breaks for C modules like `sys` or `itertools`.

Comment: fixed for C Builtin modules

Answer (score 5):

**EDIT:**

I used this solution ([source](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6464112/6900838)).

```
import distutils.sysconfig as sysconfig
import os

def std_modules():
    ret_list = []
    std_lib = sysconfig.get_python_lib(standard_lib=True)
    for top, dirs, files in os.walk(std_lib):
        for nm in files:
            if nm != '__init__.py' and nm[-3:] == '.py':
                ret_list.append(os.path.join(top, nm)[len(std_lib)+1:-3].replace('\\','.'))
    return ret_list
            
l = std_modules()
print("logging" in l)
print("os" in l)
```

Output:

```
False
True
```

This works in both Python 2 and Python 3.

**BEFORE EDIT:**

I guess, you can use Python Docs. Here are standard library parts of [Python 2 Docs](https://docs.python.org/2/library/index.html) and [Python 3 Docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/index.html). Also, you can select the exact version of Python.

Comment: I need an method that can work on the fly. 
I can save an offline list based on this list, but it'll need non trivial updates.

Comment: @YohaiDe OK, try this one.

Answer (score 2):

There is also a good answer in an old duplicate of this post: https://stackoverflow.com/a/28873415/7262247

This is how you can do it (you need to `pip install stdlib_list` first):

```
from stdlib_list import stdlib_list
import sys

all_stdlib_symbols = stdlib_list('.'.join([str(v) for v in sys.version_info[0:2]]))

module_name = 'collections'

if module_name in all_stdlib_symbols:
    print("%s is in stdlib" % module_name)
```

Comment: You need `pip install stdlib_list` first.

Comment: indeed thanks @shellcat_zero, I updated the post accordingly.

Answer (score 2):

None of the solutions above were what I wanted, so I did it yet another way. Posting here in case it's useful to anyone.

```py
import os

def standard_lib_names_gen(include_underscored=False):
    standard_lib_dir = os.path.dirname(os.__file__)
    for filename in os.listdir(standard_lib_dir):
        if not include_underscored and filename.startswith('_'):
            continue
        filepath = os.path.join(standard_lib_dir, filename)
        name, ext = os.path.splitext(filename)
        if filename.endswith('.py') and os.path.isfile(filepath):
            if str.isidentifier(name):
                yield name
        elif os.path.isdir(filepath) and '__init__.py' in os.listdir(filepath):
            yield name
```

```py
>>> standard_lib_names = set(standard_lib_names_gen(include_underscored=True))
>>> # verify that a few known libs are there (including three folders and three py files)
>>> assert {'collections', 'asyncio', 'os', 'dis', '__future__'}.issubset(standard_lib_names)
>>> # verify that other decoys are not in there
>>> assert {'__pycache__', 'LICENSE.txt', 'config-3.8-darwin', '.DS_Store'}.isdisjoint(standard_lib_names)
>>>
>>> len(standard_lib_names)
200
>>>
>>> # not including underscored
>>> standard_lib_names = set(standard_lib_names_gen(include_underscored=False))
>>> len(standard_lib_names)
184
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to check that an *actual* instance *or* class (not it's name) is in the stdlib, you can do:

```
from inspect import isclass
from sys import stdlib_module_names

def is_in_stdlib(obj: object) -> bool:
    cls = obj if isclass(obj) else type(obj)
    return cls.__module__ in stdlib_module_names
```