# How do I determine if something comes from the standard library or an external library on Python3?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-imaging-library, external

I have been asked to write code without using any of the Python external libraries (such as pandas).

I believe that https://docs.python.org/2/library/index.html
describes only standard libraries. Is it true?

In particular, how can I confirm that when I use

```
from collections import Counter
```

that "collections" belongs to the standard library?

Comment: Here's the docs to collections: https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html. Yes it does belong to the standard library.

Comment: be careful though, your link is for python 2.x. nowadays python 3.x is the go.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to determine if a module name is part of python standard library](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46441539/how-to-determine-if-a-module-name-is-part-of-python-standard-library)